# map() a function with a numpy array and lists as arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to vectorize a function which applies some simple filtering logic to a numpy array:

```py
import numpy 

def func(arr, a, b):
    sub = arr[arr[:,a] > b]
    mean = numpy.mean(sub, axis=0)
    return mean

a = numpy.array([0,1,2])
b = numpy.array([0,2,0])
arr = numpy.array([[0,2,3],[4,4,0]])

out = map(func, arr, a, b)
print(list(out))
```

However, this raises an error:

`sub = arr[arr[:,a] > b] IndexError: too many indices for array`

This seems to break because its not properly utilizing `map` and iterating over the lists `a` and `b`. How can you use a numpy array and lists as inputs to a `map` function?

Here, my expected output should be an array of arrays (3 arrays long) that are each the mean of the array--note that the actual logic I want to perform is more complicated than just calculating means, but this should get the point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what `map` is feeding your `func`:

```
In [31]: def func(arr, a, b):
    ...:    print(arr,a,b)
    ...:    return 1
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [32]: a = numpy.array([0,1,2])
    ...: b = numpy.array([0,2,0])
    ...: arr = numpy.array([[0,2,3],[4,4,0]])
    ...: 
    ...: out = map(func, arr, a, b)
    ...: list(out)
[0 2 3] 0 0
[4 4 0] 1 2
Out[32]: [1, 1]
```

transpose `arr` so it's (3,2)

```
    ...: out = map(func, arr.T, a, b)
    ...: list(out)
[0 4] 0 0
[2 4] 1 2
[3 0] 2 0
Out[33]: [1, 1, 1]
```

It's iterating over **all** arguments, not just `a` and `b`.  And using the shortest.

It's the same sort of iteration that we get from `zip`:

```
In [34]: list(zip(arr,a,b))
Out[34]: [(array([0, 2, 3]), 0, 0), (array([4, 4, 0]), 1, 2)]
In [35]: list(zip(arr.T,a,b))
Out[35]: [(array([0, 4]), 0, 0), (array([2, 4]), 1, 2), (array([3, 0]), 2, 0)]
```

Leave `arr` outside of the map, taking it as a global:

```
In [36]: def func(a, b):
    ...:     sub = arr[arr[:,a] > b]
    ...:     mean = numpy.mean(sub, axis=0)
    ...:     return mean
    ...: 
In [37]: list(map(func,a,b))
Out[37]: [array([4., 4., 0.]), array([4., 4., 0.]), array([0., 2., 3.])]
```

`map` docs:

```
map(func, *iterables) --> map object

Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.
```

---

Let's add a print to get a clearer idea of what your func is doing:

```
In [56]: def func(a, b):
    ...:     sub = arr[arr[:,a] > b]
    ...:     print(a,b,sub)
    ...:     mean = numpy.mean(sub, axis=0)
    ...:     return mean
    ...: 
In [57]: list(map(func,a,b))
0 0 [[4 4 0]]
1 2 [[4 4 0]]
2 0 [[0 2 3]]
Out[57]: [array([4., 4., 0.]), array([4., 4., 0.]), array([0., 2., 3.])]
```

With that indexing `sub` is a (1,3) array, so the `mean` does do anything interesting

Drop the `axis`, it's more interesting:

```
In [59]: def func(a, b):
    ...:     sub = arr[arr[:,a] > b]
    ...:     print(a,b,sub)
    ...:     mean = numpy.mean(sub)
    ...:     return mean
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [60]: list(map(func,a,b))
0 0 [[4 4 0]]
1 2 [[4 4 0]]
2 0 [[0 2 3]]
Out[60]: [2.6666666666666665, 2.6666666666666665, 1.6666666666666667]
```

This indexing of `arr` selects whole rows, in this case the 2nd 2 times, and the 1st once.

Comment: Excellent and poignant, thank you. Outside of leaving `arr` as global, is there no way to 'protect' arr from being iterated over by `map()`?

Comment: I added `map` docs (which is publically available).

Comment: By the way `map` is **not** numpy vectorization.